# Java XXE Injection - Billion Laughs doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, xxe

I'm trying to reproduce several xxe attacks against a java web service.

When i try to reproduce ["Billion Laughs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs) 
i always get this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>   1; columnNumber: 1; The parser has encountered more than "64,000"
>   entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the
>   application.

I've tried:

oracle **jdk1.7.0**, 
oracle **jdk1.7.0_51**, 
oracle **jdk1.7.0_55**,

All of them are throwing the same exception, and according to [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028111), versions **_51** and **_55** shouldn't

Am i missing something ?

Edit:

Works when i use "-DentityExpansionLimit=0", of course. But i need an "unpatched" jdk.

Comment: I'm unclear on the question. Billion laughs is useful for, well, laughs, but if you are trying to pull off an actual attack, you'd want to try something else.

Comment: yes you're right. but i'm trying to create a PoC/demonstration. i need to show each possible attack(quadratic blowup, billion laughs( aka xml bomb) , etc).

Comment: ahhh. Okay. You're trying to create a lab environment to demonstrate each particular issue. In that case, unfortunately I can't speak the specific environment issues you are experiencing. Good luck though.

Comment: There's nothing on the page you point to that says the billion laughs attack should work on earlier releases of JDK 1.7. The page is about a much more specific problem about exactly how the entity expansion limit is counted. The limit has been there (to protect against this attack) for many years, and it will be difficult to find a JDK old enough to contain this vulnerability.

Comment: Yes, the restriction has been there since SE5 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/xml/jaxp/JAXP-Compatibility_150.html. So it would be a matter of trying SE4.0 but that would be stupid. I obviously misunderstood the bug fix. I thought it was a restriction that was added in 7u45, and then removed again in 7u55.  Thx